# clear autocomplete suggestions from vuetifiy

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

I am using the  to display a list of cities. When a user selects a city the value is shown in the autocomplete box. When I focus again on the autocomplete  element the drop down with suggestions still displays. How do I clear the drop down suggestions after an item is selected from the drop down. I tired to clear the cityResults array which contains a list of strings of cities. This caused the selected value to be cleared too from the autocomplete element. How can I clear the drop down list?

```
 <v-autocomplete
 v-model="cityValues"
  :items="cityResults"
  outlined

  label="City"
  append-icon

  item-text="name"
  dense

 hide-no-data
  item-value="id"
   chips
   deletable-chips=""
  @change="updateCityValues($event)"
  return-object
>

</v-autocomplete>
```

Comment: Kind of a confusing question to be honest. So you want to remove all items except the one you chose in the dropdown?

Comment: @Rie- I basically want the clear the cityResults array so I don't see any more suggestions on the drop down

Comment: But do you want the dropdown to show the last item that you selected or clear it completely? Because if you clear it completely and there are no items left to choose from anymore - what's the point in displaying the dropdown in the first place? It would be pretty much non-interactive at this point. If you really wanted to achieve that, you just need to say `this.cityResults = []` in your `updateCityValues` handler

Comment: @Rie- Im trying to making something very similar to the Tags autocomplete on stack-overflow when asking a question. When I type java its shows suggestions, when I click a suggested value and type again for the next tag it doesn't still show the same suggestions it did for java. I want to build something like that

Comment: I get it now lol. Have you tried the `hide-selected` property for the v-autocomplete? This property should automatically hide all your currently selected tags from the list

Comment: @Rie- yes, but the ones I don't select are still being shown